# How to integrate $e^{1/z}*e^{1/(1-z)}*z^a*(1-z)^b$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, complex-integration

This may be a very simple and easy question.

How to compute the integral $\int_0^1  e^{1/z}*e^{1/(1-z)}*z^a*(1-z)^b dz$.

Comment: How do you know this converges?

Comment: Wolfram-Alpha tells us that this integral doesn't converge.

Comment: $e^{1/z} \to \infty$ as $z \to 0^+$ faster than any power of  $z$.